# SublimeText 3 - Nothing works to force indentation to 4 spaces

Tags: sublimetext3, indentation

### Issue:

- Can't set/change tab indentation in documents

---

### Have tried:

- With document open: >Indentation >Tab width: 4
- With document open: >Indentation >Convert Indentation to Spaces
- Adding the following to user settings:

  `"smart_indent": true,
  "tab_size": 4,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
  "trim_automatic_white_space": true,
  "trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true,
  "use_tab_stops": true,
  "word_wrap": false`
- Adding the following to the php-specific preferences:

  `"tab_size": 4,
  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true`

---

### Questions:

1. Does it seem weird that changing the spaces from the menu doesn't even work? SublimeText states that the tab indentation is 4 spaces - but it's not.
2. Does anyone know how to force SublimeText to apply a tab indentation to a document or to a project?

---

### Update:

- It looks as if ST3 is not recognising some spaces as indentation and thinks they're just spaces - see image

[image: Spaces not recognised as indentation]

- The above image is the result of converting spaces to tabs (the opposite of what I want) to see what ST3 thinks is indentation
- Does anyone know how to fix this besides going through every document
  and changing spacing on every single line?

Comment: Same problem, It does the job once you click "Convert Indentation to Spaces", bur once I SAVED, it comes back to tabs. Its a bug.

Answer (score 6):

The only command from that list that actively changes all indentation in the current file is the `> Indentation > Convert Indentation to Spaces`. The other settings only take effect from "that point on" (i.e. existing indentation will remain tabs, newly created ones will be spaces). Also, make sure you try running the command **after** selecting `Indentation > Indent using spaces`, and `Tab Width 4`

Could you check that running `Convert Indentation to Spaces`, and with `"draw_white_space": "all",` on, that indentation is shown using semi-transparent dots? Navigation with the caret will still "jump" the 4 spaces.

Only other thing I can think of is it's somehow being a read-only file.

Can't comment because I've less than 50 rep.

Comment: Thanks heaps for the reply Azriel. I can confirm that ```Convert Indentation to Spaces``` and ```"draw_white_space": "all"``` results in seeing the semi-transparent dots but although all the open documents state they're using 4 spaces, they're not. All new documents use 4 spaces but for some reason, the existing documents don't - it's very strange.

Comment: Does anyone know what is going on - it seems Sublime Text thinks that the tab spaces are set to 4 (I see 'Spaces 4' bottom right of open docs) but it's actually 2 spaces. If I Convert Indentation to Spaces then choose 4 spaces, nothing changes - it's all very strange.

Comment: Have uninstalled ST3 and related support files and reinstalled but there's still no change.

Comment: When I try to convert spaces to tabs as a test (the opposite of what I want), some spaces don't get converted to tabs - it's as if ST3 fails to recognise two spaces as indentation and thinks they're just spaces - is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

[image: view of a typical sublime text window]
There is a status bar at the very bottom of the window. If not visible go to View> Show status bar.
At the rightmost end you will see the language of the current file, Here `python`.
After that, it will show you whether you are using tabs or spaces and how many of them are being used. Click on it and you will get
[image: Indent menu from status bar second rightmost]

> Taken from https://css-tricks.com/changing-spaces-tabs-sublime-text/